# Changing master page background color through database

Tags: c#, css, sql, asp.net

Hello I am currently working on a masterpage in ASP.net core. I am trying to make the masterpage color set with a color provided in a sql database. What is the best way to do this? I need to retrieve the color from the database and then change the masterpage background with that color.

The color of the page changes depending on how the system is doing in the database. I have tried to do this seveal ways but I can not get the masterpage css to link up to the database.

This is the code in my _Layout.cshtml

```
<body id="backgroundColor">

<script type="text/javascript"> var JavascriptColor = '<%=PassedColor%>'

document.getElementById("backgroundColor").style.background = "JavascriptColor";

</script>
```

This is the code in my color.cs file

```
 string PassedColor = "pink";
```

I can't seem to get the string "pink" into my .cshtml file.

Comment: So your view isn't inheriting your _Layout.cshtml?

Comment: I don't think the value in the .cs file is being grabbed by the '<%=PassedColor%>'    I am basically trying to pass a value from a .cs file to the master page .cshtml file in an asp.net core environment.